# Loading JSX file from content server asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am facing a issue when I am trying to get my JSX file by a content server. The application has a view Test.cshtml and in this calls a jsx file to render the react portion of the UI to the 'content' div.

When I run it locally in the project using the file structure from the solution it works fine.

```
<div id="content">
    @*react renders here*@
</div>`

@section Scripts{
    <script src="_linktoReact_/react-0.14.0.js"></script>
    <script src="_linktoReact_/react-dom-0.14.0.js"></script>

    <script src="~/Scripts/JSX/test.jsx">
    </script>
}
```

But when I try to run from content server to host the files in a central location (which in this case is localhost:8111) it does not work. The file loads into the browser, but the jsx doesnt execute. This will give me an error of "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" which points to the first line of HTML in the jsx file.

```
<div id="content">
    @*react renders here*@
</div>`

@section Scripts{
    <script src="_linktoReact_/react-0.14.0.js"></script>
    <script src="_linktoReact_/react-dom-0.14.0.js"></script>

    <script src="http://localhost:8111/Scripts/JSX/test.jsx">
    </script>
}
```

So I tried adding the type tag to reference jsx, like below. This removed the "uncaught syntax error" but then doesn't give any errors but also doesn't render the react.

```
<div id="content">
    @*react renders here*@
</div>`

@section Scripts{
    <script src="_linktoReact_/react-0.14.0.js"></script>
    <script src="_linktoReact_/react-dom-0.14.0.js"></script>

    <script type="text/jsx" src="http://localhost:8111/Scripts/JSX/test.jsx">
    </script>
}
```

I tried to find the problem a few different ways and have tinkered with solutions around scoping, CORS, maybe even an issue with routing on the server, but not sure what fixes it.

*Attempts to fix:*
One suggestion was to use window instead of var like

```
var TestDataTile = React.createClass({
```

replace with

```
window.TestDataTile = React.createClass({
```

But that to is not working. I am using react-0.14.0.js, react-dom-0.14.0.js

**Tried to recompile into js file, which rendered as expected in the solution, but still some issues with some of the code in the test.js file in regard to some api calls.**

What could be causing the jsx disconnect?

Can anyone guide me towards correct direction?

Comment: More info needed. What's not working? Is there anything in the console? Any errors, anything not loaded in the network tab?

Comment: Hi Chris,
The JSX that I am using renders some content on the UI.There is no error at all but the UI is not rendered when I use the script path from the Content server.

Comment: Its literally impossible to tell. Can you create a jsfiddle to replicate?